# How to bind a set of button's IsEnabled to the specified logic?

Tags: wpf, button, binding, isenabled

There are 8 buttons named `DrawMoneyFromChannel1`, `DrawMoneyFromChannel2`, `DrawMoneyFromChannel3` and so on.

There is a `List<DeviceChannels>` which contains amount of money on each channel.

Button respectively to it's channel shoud not be enabled if the respective channel has zero amount of money.

What is the best way to organize the binding in this situation?

Answer (score 4):

Do not hard code buttons in your XAML :

```
<!-- BAD -->
<StackPanel>
  <Button x:Name="DrawMoneyFromChannel1" Click="??"
      Content="Draw money from channel 1" IsEnabled="??"/>
  <Button x:Name="DrawMoneyFromChannel2" Click="??"
      Content="Draw money from channel 2" IsEnabled="??"/>
  <Button x:Name="DrawMoneyFromChannel3" Click="??"
      Content="Draw money from channel 3" IsEnabled="??"/>
  <Button x:Name="DrawMoneyFromChannel4" Click="??"
      Content="Draw money from channel 4" IsEnabled="??"/>
  <!-- ... -->
</StackPanel>

<!-- BETTER -->
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Channels}">
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <Button Command="{Binding Draw}">
      <TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="Draw money from "/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
      </TextBlock>
    </Button>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

In this example, `Channels` is a collection of `ChannelViewModel` objects. The `ChannelViewModel` class implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and has a property `Amount`, a property `Name` and a property `Draw` which is a `ICommand`. The `ICommand` is implemented so `CanExecute` is false when `Amount` is zero.

Comment: It turns out that all buttons depend on a single CanExecute?